# Laravel VUE JS dynamic drop down menu

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Why doesn't this work?
Here is my select tag:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="provider">
        <option value="0">Select Provider</option>
        <option v-for="provider in providers" :value="provider.provider_id">{{provider.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Code which loads the data:

```
loadProviders(){
     axios.get('api/provider').then(({data}) => (this.providers = data.data));
```

data is then stored in:

```
data(){
       return{
         providers : {}
      }
  }
```

I've checked the developer networks tab of Chrome and it does return the data from the database.
However the value(provider.name) doesnt show up in the dropdown options menu.

This issue has already been solved: the model for Provider had an error all along.

Comment: Have you checked with Vue developer tools that the data of the component is what you expect?

Comment: It was empty all along, was able to fix it by checking on my provider model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you are destructuring the API response, but don't take into account that when assigning to data.

```
axios.get('api/provider').then((data) => (this.providers = data.data));
```

and

```
 axios.get('api/provider').then(({data}) => (this.providers = data));
```

both work.

Answer (score 0):

Update your select box

```
<select v-model="provider">
      <option v-for="(value,key) in provider" 
         :value="value.provider_id">
         {{value.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

Make sure you received proper data from your API.
assign data to `provider` variable. it will appeare in select box